# Dynamically loading a file based on an environment variable in Webpacker (Rails 6)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

First time for me on Stack Overflow, please be kind ;) I'll try to do my best!

**The context:**

I am working on a Rails 6 app with webpacker. This is a program that will be shared by several companies and in order to apply the 'one code, multiple setups' paradigm, we decided to move all the company related configuration files to  separate folders, and to put the company name as a variable in our .env file. We need to change some config variables as well as some geofencing data (so our customers can create a new delivery to some address). Basically that's what it looks like:

```
Project folder 
| config 
  | companies
    | a_first_company
      | rails_config.rb
      | geofencing.js
    | a_second_company
      | rails_config.rb
      | geofencing.js
    | ....
```

In the .env file:

```sh
COMPANY=a_first_company
```

And in the rails configuration (`application.rb`), we are using a simple:

```rb
require_relative "companies/#{ENV['COMPANY']}/rails_config"
```

But now, here comes the JS part! And I am running into trouble.

**The problem:**

I would like to include dynamically a JSON object in an existing script. A sample `geofencing.js` looks like that:

```js
module.exports = {
  "countries": ["be"],
  "polygon": [
    50.8917729, 4.3004608,
    ...
    50.9162381, 4.3450928,
    50.8917729, 4.3004608
  ]
}
```

And I am trying to import it as a `geofencing` variable in my existing address autocompletion script:

**`/app/javascript/plugins/places.js`**

```js
// I know it doesn't work that way, but basically that what I would like to do:
const geofencing = require(`/config/companies/${process.env.COMPANY}/geofencing`);
...

const initPlaceAutocomplete = () => {
  
    ...

    var placesAutocomplete = places(
            {
                // And use the variable here...
                insidePolygon: [geofencing.polygon],
                type: 'address',
                // And there...
                countries: geofencing.countries,
                templates: {
                    value: (suggestion) => {
                        return suggestion.name;
                    }
                },
                container: addressInput
            }
        );

     ...
}

export { initPlaceAutocomplete };
```

This file is imported in the view with a `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'delivery_new' %>`:

**`/app/javascript/packs/delivery_new.js`**

```js
import { initPlaceAutocomplete } from '../plugins/places';
initPlaceAutocomplete();

...
```

**The solution (that I haven't found yet):**

I have tried several things, like importing the file in the webpack config (`/config/webpack/environment.js`), just like in [the ProvidePlugin documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/):

```js
const {environment} = require('@rails/webpacker')
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
        geofencing: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'config', 'companies', process.env['COMPANY'], 'geofencing'))
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

... But it didn't work.

I also tried various places to import 'geofencing' in several places, with always the same result in the Chrome console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: geofencing is not defined`.

I noticed, though, that I had access to the `process.env` variables in the `places.js` script: writing `console.log(process.env['COMPANY']);` in the file prompts me the company name in the dev console when I reload the page in Chrome.

Apart from this, I have to say that I am lost. I am basically a newbie to the Webpack 'magic' ;)

Please tell me if you need more info about my setup.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to require modules using interpolation in the `require()` expression similar to your example. Try using a relative path, e.g. (assuming parent directories are siblings):

```
require(`../config/${process.env.COMPANY}/geofencing`)
```

The above expression will add *only* the COMPANY geofencing module to the bundle.

If you wish this to be dynamic, webpack can resolve the interpolation at runtime assuming the require paths are scoped to a directory; you're already doing this here with "../config/". As a result, webpack will include *all* COMPANY geofencing modules in the bundle. As for usage, I might move the require statement inside a function:

```
function initPlaceAutocomplete(company) {
  const geofencing = require(`../config/${company}/geofencing`)
  // ...
}

// usage
import { initPlaceAutocomplete } from "../plugins/places"
initPlaceAutocomplete(process.env.COMPANY)
```

At this point, this could is a good use case for [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports), i.e., webpack supports the [TC39 proposal for dynamically loading modules at runtime](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import).

Instead of `require("../config...")`, you can use the `import()` function syntax. Unlike `require()`, the `import()` function syntax resolves asynchronously.

Now webpack will bundle all the COMPANY geofencing modules, but as separate "chunks" to keep the size of your initial script down. webpack will insert code to resolve these "chunks" asynchronously at runtime. To support this, the import() expression returns a Promise so, I'm using the async/await syntax here as a result.

```js
async function initPlaceAutocomplete(company) {
  const geofencing = await import(`../companies/${company}/config`)
  
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! I just had time to come back to this issue and you solution works for me :) (at least with `require()`, I'll give a try to the `import()` later).